# PHP Force Download - Limit possible file download

Tags: php, security, download

I'm using the following to force download of MP3 files:

> http://www.aaronfagan.ca/blog/2014/how-to-use-php-to-force-a-file-download/

Basically using PHP lines to force a download

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['id']) {
        $file = $_GET['id'];
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
    }
    else {
        header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/error/');
    }
?>
```

Am I correct to understand that anyone that knows how it works could basically download any files on any website with this?

For example, if I place that file in the root of `mywebsite.com`, anyone with knowledge could use a link like the following to download any file anywhere?:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/download.php?id=http://www.anywebsite/files/file.pdf`

Or would it only work on my website?

The files I want users to be able to download are MP3 files, would there be a way to `"restrict"` the type of files the `"download.php"` would process? so this way the `"Content-Type"` be set to something for only MP3 files, this way the `"hack"` would be restricted?

Comment: Try `Content-Type: audio/mpeg`

Comment: @Tobias So far you're the only one that answered what I was looking for.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks, that's what I wanted to try, but it doesn't restrict the download type... Only tells what kind of file it is!

Comment: Nice I can get all I want if I pass the correct path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I place that file in the root of mywebsite.com, anyone
>   with knowledge could use a link like the following to download any
>   file anywhere?:
>
> http://www.mywebsite.com/download.php?id=http://www.anywebsite/files/file.pdf

If permissions open for **http://www.anywebsite/files/file.pdf** (it means you can open/download **file.pdf** with browser) you can download it remotly with your script (but as I now **basename** uses for local paths),
but usually permissions denied for direct download (you can close permissions too).

Also if you want you can add captcha to your download method to disable *grab*

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your code works only  on your website.

For serving resources from other servers you can use this script [Resource-Proxy](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy).

Good Luck

Comment: It's not at all what I was asking for. You did answer a little bit, but I actually don't want AT ALL linking to another website, I want to make SURE that my download.php will NOT because to "hack" other website. Please read the question properly.

Comment: @pSyToR Ok, sorry for my careless.

Comment: and by the way I just tried too type it myself (to a second website I have): http://www.mywebsite.com/download.php?id=http://www.myotherwebsite.com/filename.zip - And the download started of the other... So it doesn't only work on my website it can fetch files on other websites